# How to sort list of custom integers? Collections.sort()?

Tags: java, sorting

I have array of custom integers:

```
ArrayList<MyCustomInteger> list1 = new ArrayList<MyCustomInteger>
```

I need integers to be custom since i want them to hold some additional methods. Now this doesn't work for custom:

```
Collections.sort(list1);
```

How can I sort them?

Comment: Provide a custom comparator to the overloaded sort method? Or make your MyCustomInteger class implement the Comparable interface.

Comment: Make sure `MyCustomInteger` implements `Comparable<MyCustomInteger>` or provide a custom `Comparator<MyCustomInteger>`.

Comment: Allow your class to implement the comparable interface. Check out this link detailing how to do it! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: Can't you just have your custom integer inherit from the Integer class, and thus they will be compared the same way in the list when sorting?

Comment: @Malik , not sure how to do it - Eclipse throws  error: "The type MyCustomInteger cannot subclass the final class Integer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyCustomInteger` class must implement the `Comparable` interface.
Alternatively, you have to pass a `Comparator` instance to the `sort` method.

Read these:

- [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extend the Integer class?

Comment: Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html. The `Integer` class is `final`, you can't extend it.

Comment: Is there a work around to extend it? Like type alias?

Comment: No, because extending it makes no sense. How can you extend an integer?

Comment: With a wrapper class? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148679/equivalent-to-extending-a-final-class-in-java).

Comment: I know, but it's quite a mess because you have to create wrappers for all of the methods of the final class you're trying to extend. Definitely not a good solution.

Comment: I implement the Comparable. Thanks 4 second link.